# Facebook Login for an Ionic app powered by Yii2 and Drupal

Tags: angularjs, rest, drupal, yii2, ionic-framework

May be I am overcomplicating things and overthinking of a solution but this is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have an app that uses Ionic Angular JS as the frontend  with multiple restful services from the backend. I am using a combination of Drupal and Yii2.  Both of the apps can support Facbook login / sign up as web apps as the modules are available.  Ionic app by itself can use FBLogin by using NGCordova.  However, I need to do the following:

1. Login to Ionic app using Facebook Login.
2. Using this login create an account in both my Yii2 and Drupal 7 apps.  (I can sacrifice one or the other if I really need to.  I have two backends because I need one to store the custom logic an another for the content management.).
3. User should be able to create new nodes in both of the apps.  (Yii2 will have a higher priority).

Any guidance will be great.  Eventually I may expand FB login capability to Google ID as well.